# Accessing NAS4Free NFS shares from Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, dns, nfs

My previous server solution was built on top of Debian. It wasn't clever and I was happy to discover NAS4Free. We run Ubuntu 16.04 on client machines. I had NFS4 access working, using Avahi for service location.

Since moving to NAS4Free I can mount NFS shares but any attempt to use autofs (by me, at least!) fails. I saw another post which suggested that nslookup would need to work satisfactorily for autofs to work - it doesn't, on Ubuntu clients, reporting:

** server can't find nas4free: NXDOMAIN

I've searched a lot and drawn blank. Any helpful ideas would be most welcome.

In the meantime I offer everyone Christmas Greetings!

Many thanks,

Ben

Comment: You can mount NFS shares: How do you mount them (fstab, mount command, atl)? Has your machine be configured to resolve the name `nas4free`, maybe via DNS configuration or an entry in the `/etc/hosts` file? What does `ping nas4free`return? If you know the (static) address of `nas4free`, just add a corresponding line to `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: There are few results when looking for "NAS4Free and avahi". One more recent entry was https://revprez.github.io/posts/2016-06-26-avahi-conquered.html, maybe this could help you to work as you used before.

Comment: Thank you for this. I've relied on avahi/zeroconf to map names to IP addresses, possibly erroneously - I am no expert! I have mounted the shares via mount commands this time. Since the home machines concerned are all laptops I moved over to autofs in the past due to shares disappearing as laptops were suspended/resurrected. I haven't touched /etc/hosts but can certainly do so, and will experiment. Ping nas4free.local works. Since the IP address is static I can certainly add a live to /etc/hosts - that'll be the next experiment!

Comment: As you can ping _nas4free.local_, there seems to be a DNS server which resolves this name. So you don't need to add _nas4free_ to every hosts file; just mount _nas4free.local:/..._ or make _local_ one of the default search domains (look in the documentation of  your DHCP server - search for `search domain` or `domain search list`).

Comment: Interesting. I opted to experiment with /etc/hosts, adding the server name and IP address. I can ping it - fine. But I read somewhere else that autofs relies on nslookup working, which it (still) doesn't for the server address. I'll try autofs again.

Comment: Well, [this entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/autofs#NFS_network_mounts) in the Arch wiki says that "Each host name needs to be resolveable, e.g. the name and IP address in /etc/hosts or via DNS", so the hosts file should be sufficient, as the -hosts map uses the gethostbyname() system call (see [here](http://osr507doc.xinuos.com/en/NetAdminG/autoC.maps.html#autoD.about_hosts)). But try the `search` options in DHCP (as I told before) or (only for testing) add the line `search local` at the end of `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Hmm. Further delving shows symptoms of this https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=682675 - I unmount the folders and try to stop autofs and then run automount -f -v for diagnostics. I get 'already running'. Hmm. What next, I wonder?

Comment: Success, I think. I avoided nfs4. I used IP addresses in /etc/auto.nfs as I call it. The key for me to get round 'automount already running'  was to find the file in /run/autofs-running  and remove it. automount -f -v then was happy. I restarted the service and all is well so far. I shall now experiment with the DNS/avahi issue.